# "mostly" flatten a nested list

Tags: scheme, racket, flatten

I have a nested `foo` where each element is a `bar`, and I'd like to flatten the `foo`s without flattening the `bar`s.
For example:

```
(special-flatten (foo (foo (bar 2) (bar 3)) (foo (bar 4) (bar 5)))) ;=>
((bar 2) (bar 3) (bar 4) (bar 5))
```

Using the normal `flatten` from racket does not work, because I get `(bar 2 bar 3 bar 4 bar 5)`.

`foo` can be nested arbitrarily deep.

Is there a racket-y way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a predicate that determines when a sublist shouldn't be flattened, then you can do this.

```
;; An Element is a value for which element? returns true
;; element? : Any -> Boolean
(define (element? v)
  ...you-have-to-determine-this...)
```

This `element?` predicate should answer the question, "What determines when a sublist shouldn't be flattened?" In your case this means things that start with `bar` such as `(bar 2)` and `(bar 3)`.

```
;; An Element is a (cons 'bar Any)
;; element? : Any -> Boolean
(define (element? v)
  (and (pair? v) (equal? (car v) 'bar)))
```

Once this `element?` predicate is defined, you can make a flatten function based on it:

```
;; A NestedFooListofElement is one of:
;;  - Element
;;  - (cons 'foo [Listof NestedFooListofElement])
;; foo-list? : Any -> Boolean
(define (foo-list? v)
  (and (list? v) (pair? v) (equal? (car v) 'foo)))

;; special-flatten : NestedFooListofElement -> [Listof Element]
(define (special-flatten nfle)
  (cond
    [(element? nfle)  (list nfle)]
    [(foo-list? nfle) (append-map special-flatten (rest nfle))]))
```

Using it:

```
> (special-flatten '(foo (foo (bar 2) (bar 3)) (foo (bar 4) (bar 5))))
'((bar 2) (bar 3) (bar 4) (bar 5))
```

Comment: `append-map` was the special sauce I was missing. Thanks!